# How to get form element value inside Zend_Form::isValid() method?

Tags: zend-framework, validation, zend-form

I'm looking for best way of getting form element values inside isValid() method.

I had something like this isValid():

```
public function isValid($data) {

    $start = (int)($data['start_hour'] . $data['start_minute']);
    $end   = (int)($data['end_hour'] . $data['end_minute']);

    if ($start >= $end) {
        $this->getElement('start_hour')->addError('Start time should be less than end time');
        return false;
    }

    return parent::isValid($data);
}
```

but problem is that when my data structure changes I have to change validation too.
For example, now values of **start_hour**, **start_minute**, etc becomes elements of multidimensional array, and I need edit validation like

```
public function isValid($data) {

    $start = (int)($data['send']['start_hour'] . $data['send']['start_minute']);
    $end   = (int)($data['send']['end_hour'] . $data['send']['end_minute']);

    .......
}
```

It would be great to get value of element by permanent key (like element name), so my isValid could looks like:

```
public function isValid($data) {

    $start = (int)($this->getElement('start_hour')->getValue() . $this->getElement('start_minute')->getValue());
    $end   = (int)($this->getElement('end_hour')->getValue() . $this->getElement('end_minute')->getValue());

    .......
}
```

but **$this->getElement('start_hour')->getValue()** inside validation method return an empty value.

Is this possible to get element value in such way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code takes place in the `isValid()` method of the form, then sure you could do it as you have described. It's just that `isValid()` usually needs some data passed - `$form->isValid($_POST)`, for example -  and you just end up ignoring it (assuming the parent is `Zend_Form`, which has an empty `isValid()` method; intermediate ancestors could potentially inspect the passed data). I would consider that to be potentially confusing.

Al alternative could be to create a [custom validator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html), attach it to *one* of the form elements (say, the `start_hour` elements). The signature for the validator's `isValid()` can use the optional `$context` parameter - `isValid($value, $context = null)`. When you call `$form->isValid($data)`, it will pass that `$data` as the `$context` to the the element validator. You can then use that `$context` variable to inspect the other values (`start_min`, `end_hour`, `end_min`, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Try with $this->getValue('start_hour');

Comment: it returns an empty value too

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

```
$form->populate($data)
```

Before calling isValid that way the data will be in your form.
Then `$this->getValue('start_hour');` should work from within `isValid()`.

So to be sure:
Somewhere in your code (probably controller) there is somthing like:

```
    $this->view->form = new MyForm();
$this->populate($data); //add this
if($this->view->form->isValid($data)){
//do stuff
}
```